# 'Premature end of Content-Length' with Spark Application using s3a

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, apache-spark-sql, emr

I'm writing a Spark based application which works around a pretty huge data stored on s3. It's about **15 TB** in size uncompressed. Data is laid across multiple small LZO compressed files files, varying from 10-100MB.

By default the job spawns 130k tasks while reading dataset and mapping it to schema.

And then it fails around 70k tasks completions and after ~20 tasks failure.

**Exception:**

```
WARN lzo.LzopInputStream: IOException in getCompressedData; likely LZO corruption.
    org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body
```

Looks like the s3 connection is getting closed prematurely.

**I have tried nearly 40 different combos of configurations.**

**To summarize them:** 1 executor to 3 executors per node, 18GB to 42GB `--executor-memory`, 3-5 `--executor-cores`, 1.8GB-4.0 GB `spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead`, Both, Kryo and Default Java serializers, 0.5 to 0.35 `spark.memory.storageFraction`, default, 130000 to 200000 partitions for bigger dataset. default, 200 to 2001 `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions`.

**And most importantly:** 100 to 2048 `fs.s3a.connection.maximum` property.

[This seems to be most relevant property to exception.]

[In all cases, driver was set to memory = 51GB, cores = 12, `MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER` level for caching]

Nothing worked!

If I run the program with half of the bigger dataset size (7.5TB), it finishes successfully in 1.5 hr.

1. What could I be doing wrong?
2. How do I determine the optimal value for `fs.s3a.connection.maximum`?
3. Is it possible that the s3 clients are getting GCed?

Any help will be appreciated!

***Environment:***

AWS EMR 5.7.0, 60 x i2.2xlarge SPOT Instances (16 vCPU, 61GB RAM, 2 x 800GB SSD), Spark 2.1.0

YARN is used as resource manager.

***Code:***

It's a fairly simple job, doing something like this:

```
val sl = StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER

sparkSession.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("io.compression.codecs", "com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzopCodec")
sparkSession.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
sparkSession.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.setInt("fs.s3a.connection.maximum", 1200)

val dataset_1: DataFrame = sparkSession
    .read
    .format("csv")
    .option("delimiter", ",")
    .schema(<schema: StructType>)
    .csv("s3a://...")
    .select("ID")   //15 TB

dataset_1.persist(sl)

print(dataset_1.count())

tmp = dataset_1.groupBy(“ID”).agg(count("*").alias("count_id”))
tmp2 = tmp.groupBy("count_id").agg(count("*").alias(“count_count_id”))
tmp2.write.csv(…)

dataset_1.unpersist()
```

***Full Stacktrace:***

```
17/08/21 20:02:36 INFO compress.CodecPool: Got brand-new decompressor [.lzo]
17/08/21 20:06:18 WARN lzo.LzopInputStream: IOException in getCompressedData; likely LZO corruption.
org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected: 79627927; received: 19388396
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthInputStream.read(ContentLengthInputStream.java:180)
        at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.read(EofSensorInputStream.java:137)
        at com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.read(SdkFilterInputStream.java:72)
        at com.amazonaws.event.ProgressInputStream.read(ProgressInputStream.java:151)
        at com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.read(SdkFilterInputStream.java:72)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.S3ObjectInputStream.read(S3ObjectInputStream.java:155)
        at com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.read(SdkFilterInputStream.java:72)
        at com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.read(SdkFilterInputStream.java:72)
        at com.amazonaws.event.ProgressInputStream.read(ProgressInputStream.java:151)
        at com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.read(SdkFilterInputStream.java:72)
        at com.amazonaws.util.LengthCheckInputStream.read(LengthCheckInputStream.java:108)
        at com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.read(SdkFilterInputStream.java:72)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.S3ObjectInputStream.read(S3ObjectInputStream.java:155)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AInputStream.read(S3AInputStream.java:160)
        at java.io.DataInputStream.read(DataInputStream.java:149)
        at com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzopInputStream.readFully(LzopInputStream.java:73)
        at com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzopInputStream.getCompressedData(LzopInputStream.java:321)
        at com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzopInputStream.decompress(LzopInputStream.java:261)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DecompressorStream.read(DecompressorStream.java:85)
        at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.fillBuffer(LineReader.java:180)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readDefaultLine(LineReader.java:216)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readLine(LineReader.java:174)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.LineRecordReader.nextKeyValue(LineRecordReader.java:186)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.RecordReaderIterator.hasNext(RecordReaderIterator.scala:39)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.HadoopFileLinesReader.hasNext(HadoopFileLinesReader.scala:50)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:461)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:439)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:109)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:377)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.InMemoryRelation$$anonfun$1$$anon$1.next(InMemoryRelation.scala:99)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.InMemoryRelation$$anonfun$1$$anon$1.next(InMemoryRelation.scala:91)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.memory.MemoryStore.putIteratorAsBytes(MemoryStore.scala:364)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1021)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:996)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPut(BlockManager.scala:936)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPutIterator(BlockManager.scala:996)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getOrElseUpdate(BlockManager.scala:700)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.getOrCompute(RDD.scala:334)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:285)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
```

**EDIT:** We have another service which consume exactly same logs, it works just fine. But it uses old "s3://" scheme and is based on Spark-1.6. I'll try using "s3://" instead of "s3a://".

Comment: Are you able to validate that you do not have a corrupted file within your 130k files ? Such a validation could be performed by loading each file and counting line number for example.

Comment: @glefait I just added an Edit.

Comment: This issue sometimes occur due to incompatible aws sdk can you try using this combination of sdk libraries aws-java-sdk-1.7.4 and hadoop-aws-2.7.3 .Also try setting maximum connection to some small number say 800.Hope this will solve your problem.You can refer to discussion on this  jira https://jira.snappydata.io/browse/SNAP-1552 for more info

Comment: If you are using Amazon EMR, you cannot use the s3a connector..you must use s3://. This also means that the fs.s3a settings won't do anything

Comment: Thanks for the response guys! Switch from s3a -> s3 significantly reduced task failures due to these errors, but few are still failing. Now, I'm trying out downgrading aws-java-sdk from 1.10.77 -> 1.7.4. The problem is I need other AWS components (s3, emr, sqs) too in my build. I'm not able to find corresponding JARs with 1.7.4 version in any standard repos. I can keep sdk at 1.7.4 and other aws jars at 1.10.77, but that will be really dirty! Any idea?

Comment: you'll have to build a version of hadoop against the later SDK; maybe wait for the 3.0 beta coming out in september

Comment: I don't know if this would help your situation, but when I got this error, it went away when a manually added all the `hadoop-*` maven dependencies to put them all at version `3.3.0` rather than the version `2.7.4` that spark had pulled in.